# Secondary SSD stuck as read only

Tags: 14.04, ssd, fstab, read-only

I am having trouble getting my second SSD to work with Linux. I recently switched from Windows to Ubuntu 14.04 and I am still learning Linux. I can see my second drive under Devices in the File Manager, but it is stuck as read-only. If I right click, go to Properties, then Permissions, all the options are greyed out. I tried searching for information and found a few posts about mounting drives. I tried adding this line to fstab,

```
UUID="502fd123-7748-463c-9155-ad5744a4804b"  /media/Calvin  ext4  defaults,windows_names,locale=en_CA.utf8  0 0
```

but that doesn't help. I ran `fdisk -l` and got this output;

```
Disk /dev/sda: 120.0 GB, 120034123776 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 14593 cylinders, total 234441648 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000bee68

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   200988671   100493312   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       200990718   234440703    16724993    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       200990720   234440703    16724992   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 240.1 GB, 240057409536 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 29185 cylinders, total 468862128 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000448ac

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048   468860927   234429440    5  Extended
/dev/sdb5            4096   468860927   234428416   83  Linux
```

The output of `mount | grep /dev/sdb` is;

```
/dev/sdb5 on /media/calvin/Storage type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If there is any other information I should have provided please let me know and I will add it as soon as I am able.

Comment: Can you add the output of `mount | grep /dev/sdb`?